# C++ Boost UDP receiver fails when put into thread

Tags: c++, boost, udp, receiver

I have a UDP receiver that works.  The code is here:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

std::string getMyIp()
{
    std::string result;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service netService;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver   resolver(netService);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), "google.com", "");
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::resolver::iterator endpoints = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::endpoint ep = *endpoints;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::socket socket(netService);
        socket.connect(ep);
        boost::asio::ip::address addr = socket.local_endpoint().address();
        result = addr.to_string();
        //std::cout << "My IP according to google is: " << results << std::endl;

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not deal with socket. Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}

class receiver
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
    std::array<char, 1024> data_;

public:
    receiver(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
        const boost::asio::ip::address& listen_address,
        const boost::asio::ip::address& multicast_address,
        unsigned short multicast_port = 13000)
        : socket_(io_service)
    {
        // Create the socket so that multiple may be bound to the same address.
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(listen_address, multicast_port);
        socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

        // Join the multicast group.
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));
        do_receive();
    }

private:
    void do_receive()
    {
        socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data_), sender_endpoint_, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout.write(data_.data(), length);
                std::cout << std::endl;
                do_receive();
            }
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        receiver r(io_service, boost::asio::ip::make_address(getMyIp()), boost::asio::ip::make_address("224.0.0.0"), 13000);
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to put the receiver code into a thread inside a class so I can do other things beside it:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

std::string getMyIp()
{
    std::string result;
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service netService;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver   resolver(netService);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), "google.com", "");
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::resolver::iterator endpoints = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::endpoint ep = *endpoints;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::udp::socket socket(netService);
        socket.connect(ep);
        boost::asio::ip::address addr = socket.local_endpoint().address();
        result = addr.to_string();
        //std::cout << "My IP according to google is: " << results << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not deal with socket. Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}

class UdpReceiver
{
private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
    std::array<char, 1024> data_;

    string address_send, address_recv;
    unsigned short port_send, port_recv;
    boost::thread_group threads;            // thread group
    boost::thread* thread_main;             // main thread
    boost::thread* thread_receive;          // receive thread
    boost::thread* thread_send;             // get/send thread
    boost::mutex stopMutex;
    bool initialize = false;
    bool stop, showBroadcast;
    int i_send, i_recv, i_operator,
        interval_send, interval_recv, interval_operator,
        mode;
    string message_send, message_recv;
    string message_STOP = "STOP";

public:
    // constructor
    UdpReceiver(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::string address, unsigned short port, int interval, int mode, bool show = false)
        : socket_(io_service),
        showBroadcast(show)
    {
        initialize = false;
        Initialize(io_service, show);
    }

    UdpReceiver(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, bool show = false)
        : socket_(io_service),
        showBroadcast(show)
    {
        Initialize(io_service, show);
    }

    // destructor
    ~UdpReceiver()
    {
        // show exit message
        cout << "Exiting UDP Core." << endl;
    }

    // initialize
    void Initialize(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, bool show = false)
    {
        if (initialize == false)
        {
            GetMode(true);
            GetInfo(true);
        }

        CreateEndpoint(io_service);
        CreateThreads();
        stop = false;
        showBroadcast = show;
        i_send = 0;
        i_recv = 0;
        i_operator = 0;
        message_send.clear();
        message_recv.clear();
        initialize = true;          // clear flag
    }

    void GetMode(bool default_value = false)
    {
        std::string input;
        if (default_value)
        {
            mode = 0;           
        }
        else
        {
            string prompt = "Set mode:\n0/other - Listen\n1 - Send\nEnter your choice: ";
            cout << prompt;
            getline(cin, input);

            try
            {
                mode = stoi(input);

                // set default mode to Listen
                if (mode > 1)
                    mode = 0;
            }
            catch (exception ec)
            {
                cout << "Error converting mode: " << ec.what() << endl;
                Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    void GetInfo(bool default_value = false)
    {
        // always called after GetMode()
        string address;
        unsigned short port;
        int interval;

        if (default_value)
        {
            address = getMyIp();
            port = 13000;
            interval = 500;
        }

        switch (mode)
        {
        case 0:
            address_recv = address;
            port_recv = port;
            interval_recv = interval;
            break;

        case 1:
            address_send = address;
            port_send = port;
            interval_send = interval;
            break;

        default:
            // already set to 0 in GetMode()
            break;
        }
    }

    void CreateEndpoint(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        // Create the socket so that multiple may be bound to the same address.
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(address_recv), port_recv);
        socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

        // Join the multicast group.
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("224.0.0.0")));     
    }

    void CreateThreads()
    {
        thread_main = new boost::thread(boost::ref(*this));
        interval_operator = 500;    // default value

        switch (mode)
        {
        case 0:
            thread_receive = new boost::thread(&UdpReceiver::Callable_Receive, this);
            threads.add_thread(thread_receive);
            break;

        default:
            // already set to 0 in GetMode()
            break;
        }
    }

    // start the threads
    void Start()
    {
        // Wait till they are finished
        threads.join_all();
    }

    // stop the threads
    void Stop()
    {
        // warning message
        cout << "Stopping all threads." << endl;

        // signal the threads to stop (thread-safe)
        stopMutex.lock();
        stop = true;
        stopMutex.unlock();

        // wait for the threads to finish
        thread_main->interrupt();   // in case not interrupted by operator()
        threads.interrupt_all();
        threads.join_all();

        // close socket after everything closes
        //socketPtr->close();
        socket_.close();
    }

    void Callable_Receive()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            stopMutex.lock();
            socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(data_), sender_endpoint_, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    //cout << message_recv << endl;
                    std::cout.write(data_.data(), length);
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                    Callable_Receive();
                }
            });
            stopMutex.unlock();
            //cout << i_recv << endl;
            ++i_recv;
        }
    }

    // Thread function
    void operator () ()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (message_send == message_STOP)
            {
                try
                {
                    this->Stop();
                }
                catch (exception e)
                {
                    cout << e.what() << endl;
                }
            }

            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(interval_operator));
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        UdpReceiver mt(io_service, false);
        mt.Start();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The async receive is inside Callable_Receive(), which is inside by  thread_receive.  I can see that thread running when the counter is printed on screen  (which I comment out).  However, the async_receive_from() never receives anything.  Could someone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably deadlock in *Callable_Receive*. In thread with `Callable_Receive` as body of thread you are calling `stopMutex.lock` before invoking `async_receive_from` function. `async_receive_from` returns immediately, but we don't know when lambda object passed as third paremeter to `async_receive_from` will be called. When body of lambda object is executed, you are calling `Callable_Receive` function, if `stopMutex` was locked (thread with `Callable_Receive` is still running and next iteration in while loop is being done) and you try to lock it again, you would get deadlock - on `boost::mutex` you cannot call lock method while mutex is already being locked by the same thread.

You should read about `boost::recursive_mutex` if you want to resolve this issue.

Comment: Replace `boost::mutex` by `boost::resursive_mutex`.